# Is it possible to see somewhere in Instagram how many followers you have exactly, after it started to count them with "k"s?

Tags: instagram

In Instagram, once you reach 10,000 followers it starts to shows them with "k"s, for example, 10,1k followers. Is it possible somewhere to see how many of them you have exactly, so you can check if daily if the account is growing or decreasing in followers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this, inspecting the element with Google Chrome you can see in the source code exactly how many followers you have.